# What's the name of that popular design?

Tags: vector, illustration, style-identification, line-art

I'm seeing this beautiful design more and more often. It's often made of lines of the same width, sometimes with only one type of color or with only basic colors. Anyone have an idea of an "official" name for that?

[image: Name for that design?]

Comment: Actually the image has multiple lineweights. Ane no things dont have names just descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of this illustration just tag it with "Outline"
You can see on his Dribbble that his style is very consistent and he name it "Outline Illustrations" https://dribbble.com/jucha
But there's no "Official" name for it.

Other artist have this style too https://dribbble.com/Madebyelvis